# impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT

Tags: mysql

I have gone through your answers for the above question and the options you guys presented me. I have tried changing the `binlog_format=Mixed` in MySQL workbench UI but the option was not refelecting on the UI after I apply the changes. Can anyone help me how to change the `BINLOG_FORMAT` either in UI or command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with InnoDb tables and I changed my binlog_foramt to ROW in Workbench. It is essential to stop and start the server for this change to take effect. After this I was able to run the INSERT statement in an sql script.